# Setting the style.property to a textarea via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to add rows to a table dynamically using the below code:

```
function addRowToTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('targets');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);    

  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.name = 'target' + iteration;
  el.id = 'target' + iteration;
  el.style.property="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;";
  cellRight.appendChild(el);
}
```

Everything works except the `el.style.property`. I have tried `el.style` previously.

How can this be fixed?

[Here is the page (partially)](http://sen.dpwebdev.co.uk/addrowsissue.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`style.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration) instead of `style.property`.

Since your styles look constant, consider storing the style properties in a stylesheet, and add the style using a class identifier:

```
<style> <!-- Inside the head -->
.myclassname {
    margin:4px;
    max-width:400px;
    width:400px;
    max-height:
    35px; height:35px;
}
</style>

// Replace el.style.... with:
el.className = 'myclassname';
```

Answer (score 0):

You set each style individually, ie:

`el.style.margin = "4px"`

You tagged the question as jQuery, so you can also use this notation which is nicer:

```
$(el).css({
  margin: "4px",
  maxWidth: "400px",
  width: "400px",
  maxHeight: "35px",
  height: "35px"
});
```

That being said, if you plan on doing this frequently - you should really just define a class which matches these properties:

```
.table-row {
  margin: 4px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

and then add the class to the element.

```
// in JavaScript
el.classList.add("table-row");

// in jQuery
$(el).addClass("table-row");
```